# MomentJS : Issue subtracting minutes

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

This is my code that is deployed on Parse.com CloudCode :

```
var now = new Date()
var then = moment(now).subtract(20, "minutes").toDate()

console.log(now)
console.log(then)
```

Why does `now === then` ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know you were wrong, but for me works properly. No issues.

```
>var now = new Date()
>var then = moment(now).subtract(20, "minutes").toDate()
>console.log(now)
>console.log(then)
VM145:5 Thu Jan 21 2016 17:26:48 GMT+0100 (CET)
VM145:6 Thu Jan 21 2016 17:06:48 GMT+0100 (CET)
undefined
>now === then
false
```

Comment: I've tried again, checked everything, still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and had to do something similar to this:

```
const now = new Date()
const nowCopy = new Date()
const then = moment(nowCopy).subtract(20, "minutes").toDate()

console.log(now)
console.log(then)
```

I know it's not the most elegant solution but it appears your "now" variable is getting mutated when you run an operation on it to get your "then" variable

Answer (score 4):

**One line answer:**

```
moment(Date.now()).subtract(60, 'minutes').format()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue and solved it.

@rishikarri is right, the moment is getting mutated.

> All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do so implicitly or explicitly.

As an alternative to his answer and for future reference, i propose using `clone` as solution.

There are two ways to clone a moment (According to [moment docs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/12-moment-clone/)):

Using `moment()`:

```js
var a = moment([2012]);
var b = moment(a);
a.year(2000);
b.year(); // 2012
```

Using `.clone()`:

```js
var a = moment([2012]);
var b = a.clone();
a.year(2000);
b.year(); // 2012
```

All credit goes to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try this it work fine with me

```js
let startTime = moment().format('LT');
let subtract = moment(new Date()).subtract(5,"minutes").format('LT');
```

startTime 12:03 AM

subtract 11:58 PM

Answer (score 0):

If the time is in this format `2022-04-22T15:10:50+05:00`
and you want return in the same format then use

`moment(startTime).subtract(10, 'minutes').format()`

Answer (score 0):

**try using string first then number similiar to this**

```
     let formattedDate = moment(alarmSchedule).subtract('minutes',20).format();
     console.log(formattedDate); // will substract mins from  alarmSchedule time
```

Worked for me!